# How to detect increases and decreases of values per column by condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
id      col1    col2   col3
111     22      3      10
222     21      4      11
333     22      5      5
444     5       3      4
555     6       3      4
666     4       4      3
777     7       2      8
```

I need to solve a tricky task. I want to find all columns that have increases in values when `col1` values are higher than `20`. By "increase in value" I mean a value greater than a column median by at least 30% for at least 65% of rows of `col1` when `col1` values are higher than `20`.

In my example, there are 3 rows when `col1` values are higher than `20`:

```
id      col1    col2   col3
111     22      3      10
222     21      4      11
333     22      5      5
```

Among these rows, the 1st and 2nd rows of `col3` have increases in values by at least 30% with respect to median (the median of `col3` is equal to 5). This condition does not apply to 3rd row of `col3`, but it's fine since it should work for at least 65% of rows, i.e. 65% of 3 rows is 1.95 ~2 rows.

The expected output is (a different output format is also fine, but it should be clear that `col3` was identified):

```
col3
```

Comment: What is the question? Welcome to SO please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: This is a very confusingly worded question. This needs to be explained better, I really don't know where to start to answer this

Comment: @MattW.: I gave an example. Sorry if it's still unclear.  Basically, there are 2 conditions: 1) filter `df` by `ds = df[df["col1"]>20]`, 2) from `ds` select columns that have row values greater than their medians (greater by 30%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, in your example, you should output `col2` and `col3`

```
medians = df.median()

s = df[df.col1.gt(20)]

base = s.gt(medians + 0.3 * medians.abs())

(base.sum()/base.count()).gt(0.65)
```

---

```
col2     True
col3     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 22, 1: 21, 2:22, 3:5, 4: 6, 5: 4, 6:7}, 
                  'col2': {0:3, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5:4, 6:2}, 'col3': {0: 10, 1:11, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4:4, 5:3, 6:8} } )


col_cutoff = df.loc[df['col1'] > 20]['col1'].count() * 0.65
median_increase = df.median() * 1.3
median_increase = median_increase.to_dict()

cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('col1')]
candidates = []
for col in cols:
    if df[df[col] > median_increase[col]][col].count() > col_cutoff:
        candidates.append(col)
print(candidates)
```

medians:

```
col1    7.0
col2    3.0
col3    5.0
dtype: float64
```

median 30%  increase:

```
col1    9.1
col2    3.9
col3    6.5
dtype: float64
```

column 2 has 2 values larger than 3.9 and 2 > 1.95

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   22  3   10
1   21  4   11
2   22  5   5
```